# c array of pointers pointing to string arrays

Tags: c, pointers

i am aiming create an array of pointers,in which each pointer will point to an array of strings.for example
array of strings of this sort:

```
arr=["hello","my","name","is"];
```

and the pointer array of this sort:

```
pointer[1]=&arr;
```

how can i declare the array of pointers?
this is what is able to create,yet i am not sure it is correct
    char * (*Line)[Lines(Dictionary)];

i will be more than glad to receive a possible solution to the matter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const char* arr[] = { "hello", "my", "name", "is" };
const char** pointer[] = { &arr };
```

Comment: Voted up. Simple and in my opinion an elegant way to do so. Never thought of this possibility before :)

Comment: i actually meant an array of pointers,each pointing to an array of words.(like arr)

Comment: `pointer` here is an array of pointers, each pointing to an array of words (specifically, in the example there is an array of size one, and its element points to `arr` which is an array of words).  I think this is what you are asking for--if not please explain in much more detail.

Answer (score 0):

You want to create an array of pointers that can hold addresses of strings right.
Below is the simple code.

```
int main()

{

char * ptr[20];// THIS IS AN ARRAY OF POINTERS.
ptr[2]="HELLO";
ptr[3]="HELLLO";
ptr[4]="HELLLLO";
ptr[5]="HELLLLLO";
int i;
for(i=2;i<6;i++)

{
  puts(ptr[i]);
}

return 0;
}
```