# Using values from an array of pointes in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I have an array of pointers.  How do you get the values of the arrays that they point to?

```
int main() {
    const int violet[3] = { 128, 0, 256 };
    const int springGreen[3] = { 0, 256, 128 };
    const int orange[3] = { 256, 128, 0 };
    
    const int (*colorOrder[3])[3] = { &orange, &violet, &springGreen };
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            cout << *colorOrder[i][j];
            if (j < 2) { cout << ","; }
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
}
```

The code above should output:

```
256,128,0
128,0,256
0,256,128
```

but what it actually outputs is:

```
256,0,128
128,0,1144230067
0,128,0
```

I tried to implement the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20163082/c-array-of-pointers-pointing-to-string-arrays), but it doesn't seem to work with int arrays.  I feel that the issue has to be with my knowledge (or lack thereof) of pointers.  Can someone explain what is going on here?

Comment: Threw this at a couple sanitizers with `-fsanitize=address,undefined` to see what it thinks: https://godbolt.org/z/rzbhGhGoP Definitely a bug in there.

Comment: I recommend using parenthesis for clarity:  `cout << (*(colorOrder[i]))[j] << "\n";`

Comment: You should probably have the same number of parenthesis in the use as in the declaration.

Comment: Colors are not arrays, and don't use pointers when you don't have too.

Comment: You may want to use `std::tuple` and `std::vector` here. Even better, a proper RGB color `class` you can write an `operator<<` helper for that formats it, meaning you just do `std::cout << color << std::endl`. Super easy.

Comment: @tadman I object to using std::tuple, that type has no symantic meaning. It is NOT a color. std::tuple is a type to be used in (meta) template programming only.

Comment: @PepijnKramer It's a start, and you refactor that later to a proper `class` or `struct`. This is all part of a process of refinement.

Comment: @PepijnKramer `using color = std::tuple<int,int,int>;` - i would say that does the job just fine. These templates are there to be USED.

Comment: @ABaumstumpf That is just syntactic sugar, not a semantically new type (strong type). Say I have a function accepting a set_color(std::tuple<int,int,int> color) it will accept any such tuple even if it does not represent a color. By just typing those few lines and declaring an explicit struct for your color you can't make those mistakes. These kind of things become very important in big groups with a lot of engineers working on the code. Mantra : "Say what you mean". The use of these types is within (meta) template library code that is supposed to be generic (and semantics is not known yet).

Comment: Side note: When sorting this stuff out, use easily identifiable numbers and patterns in your test arrays. It's a lot easier to see that 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 printed out wrong and just how wrong than you can with the current number choices.

Comment: @PepijnKramer True - just with `using` and a tuple it will not be a new type, but it still is a different type from just 3 random integers - and that we do not have strong typedefs is just a long-standing language defect that needs to be fixed.

Comment: @ABaumstumpf Yup, the strong type alias is severly missing.

Answer (score 2):

The variable `colorOrder` is an array of pointers.
So to get a pointer to the array of color values, you'll need to dereference the `colorOrder` item:

```
*(colorOrder[color_group_index]);
```

To get the color value out of the group, you can use `operator[]`:

```
(*(colorOrder[color_group_index]))[color_value_index]);
```

I recommend using a color structure to make this more readable:

```
struct Pixel
{
    uint8_t  quantity_of_red;
    uint8_t  quantity_of_green;
    uint8_t  quantity_of_blue;
};

Pixel violet_Pixel{128, 0, 250};
Pixel spring_green_Pixel{ 0, 250, 128 };
Pixel orange_Pixel = { 250, 128, 0 };

std::vector<Pixel> pixel_colors{violet_Pixel, spring_green_Pixel, orange_Pixel};
```

Also, this technique allows you to customize the output:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Pixel& p)
{
  out << "[Red: " << p.quantity_red << "\n";
  out << "Green: " << p.quantity_green << "\n";
  out << "Blue: " << p.quantity_blue << "]\n";
  return out;
}

//...
std::cout << violet_Pixel;
```

My recommendation is to use `struct` or `class` when possible and leave the arrays to FORTRAN.

### Edit 1: Another Initialization scheme

There is another initialization scheme which is more readable (not completely sure about the syntax, but somebody will correct me as necessary):

```
Pixel teal_Pixel =
{
  .quantity_red = 255;
  .quantity_green = 128;
  .quantity_blue = 255;
};
```

IMHO, the focus should be more about readability than efficiency.  Usually code with high readability have fewer injected defects.  Fewer defects is the name of the game in professional software development.

Comment: Recommend throwing the asker a bone and showing how operator precedence caused the error.

Comment: You should not have a value of 256 for a `uint8_t`  in your source.

Comment: Changed values of 256 to 250 per @ABaumstumpf.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution without pointers and all your data defined as much as possible at compile time.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <cstdint>
#include <format>

// when you can name things make structs.
// note for color using a byte value instead of an int is more common.
struct color_t
{
    std::uint8_t red;
    std::uint8_t green;
    std::uint8_t blue;
};

// define some compile time constants
static constexpr color_t violet{ 127, 0, 255 };
static constexpr color_t spring_green{ 0, 127, 255 };
static constexpr color_t orange{ 255, 127, 0 };

// now you can define an array with the order you need.
static constexpr std::array<color_t, 3> ordered_colors{ orange, violet, spring_green };

// overload output operator<< for color keeps your code later
// more clean and allows you to use other streams (than std::cout) as well.
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const color_t& color)
{
    os << std::format("[{},{},{}]", color.red, color.green, color.blue);
    return os;
}


int main()
{
    // use range based for loops when you can. 
    for (const auto& color : ordered_colors)
    {
        std::cout << color << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course using a struct/class for the colors is the better way.
Without any extra structs, class or anything else - so if you want to go to the lowest, most c-like way:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    unsigned char colors[3][3]{
        {128,0,255},
        {0,255,128},
        {255,128,0} };

    for( const unsigned char (&col)[3] : colors )
    {
        for( const unsigned char &value : col )
        {
            std::cout << std::to_string(value) << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

}
```

But i would highly advice using a struct as described in the other answer as that makes your code a lot more readable which is godsent when you are not that well-versed with c++ yet.

And  - you should mention that you are using an arduino in your question cause that prohibits several approaches and makes others undesirable due to dynamic memory.

Answer (score -1):

Thomas provided the answer with `(*(colorOrder[i]))[j]`:

```
int main() {
    const int violet[3] = { 128, 0, 256 };
    const int springGreen[3] = { 0, 256, 128 };
    const int orange[3] = { 256, 128, 0 };
    
    const int (*(colorOrder[3]))[3] = { &orange, &violet, &springGreen };
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            cout << (*(colorOrder[i]))[j];
            if (j < 2) { cout << ","; }
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
}
```

I am interested in structs but I will need to do more research.  These actually aren't pixels, they're for a Auduino LED lightstrip.  The lightstrip builds colors by using 3 ints for the brightness levels of the red, green, and blue LEDs for each light on the strip.

Comment: An answer without an explanation of what went wrong and why the proposed solution fixes the problem isn't a good answer.

Comment: You REALLY should mention that this is about an Arduino in the actual question - that  changes a lot.